# Why my vim plugin javacomplete search all my projects files everytime when it need complete

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I installed the plugin javacomplete to stimulate my java coding work by tags all jdk sources files.

Except for it speed up the package omnicomplete, some times I type code in the class block, it always search my project files for complete too.

Ex:
When i entered :
`FileOutputStream out = new F` , and every matched symbol appears.
But when i entered:
`new StringBuffer().` , after I entered the dot, and it begin to search all my project files, I don't know what happened

I disabled the ctrlp and superTab, the fllowing is my config snippet:

```
1        autocmd FileType java setlocal omnifunc=javacomplete#Complete
930      autocmd FileType java setlocal completefunc=javacomplete#CompleteParamsInfo
```

This has been a burden for my Work.

Anyone who knows what's wrong?
I think this may be caused by javacomplete itself.

Comment: What do you type after the dot? `<C-x><C-o>`? `<C-n>`? `<C-p>`? Something else? Nothing because you have an autocompletion plugin that you forgot to tell us about?

Comment: @romainl I use the default OmniComplete, and enter <c-x><c-o>